# Should OutputCacheProfiles (in webconfig) be accessible under a medium trust environment?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, outputcache, medium-trust

I'm trying to use DevTrends Donut Caching in an MVC app in a shared hosting environment.

When I upload the app I get this error:

> System.Security.SecurityException:  MvcDonutCaching does not have
>   permission to read web.config section 'OutputCacheSettingsSection'.

The host provider says that this restriction is due to the Medium Trust environment.

While I am not knowledgable enough to argue with this, it seems strange / unreasonable that basic Web.Config settings are unavailable under medium trust.

Plus, at the bottom of [this workitem](http://mvcdonutcaching.codeplex.com/workitem/2428), from 2012, the author states that:

> I have added some code to allow MvcDonutCaching to be used in a strict
>   Medium Trust environment

***Should I be able to access these settings in a medium trust environment?***

The caching settings that I am using in web.config are like this:

```
  <system.web>
    <caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
        <outputCacheProfiles>
          <add name="CacheFor1Hour" duration="3600" varyByParam="none" />
          <add name="RecacheOnUpdate" duration="2419200" varyByParam="*" />
          <add name="Dashboard" duration="86400" varyByParam="*" varyByCustom="User" location="Server" />
        </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
    </caching>
  </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer here: http://mvcdonutcaching.codeplex.com/workitem/2466

So it looks like you just can't do it in a strict Medium Trust environment.  I wish my hosting company were like "most hosting companies" in the quote below...  :-(

> Thank you for the comprehensive description. I have tracked down the
>   problem. Because you have a strict medium trust environment,
>   MvcDonutCaching cannot access the ConfigurationSection from the
>   web.config that stores cache profiles. I have improved the code to
>   provide a meaningful error message, but without that permission, it is
>   not possible to use cache profiles. Most hosting environments modify
>   the Medium trust settings to allow access to configuration sections,
>   so if you own the server, this is one option open to you. Otherwise,
>   to use MvcDonutCaching, you will need to avoid cache profiles and add
>   duration to the attribute itself.